# Printing an Asp.net webpage running on android to mobile printer

Tags: android, asp.net, printing

I have an asp.net web page which generates invoices / receipts. The site is running on a smart device. We use Zebra mobile printers to print the invoice / receipts which is working fine on windows mobile.

But now we would like to shift to the android based smart devices. We have no knowledge of java and hence would like to continue using the Asp.net website. Please guide as to how we can print from a website developed in asp. to a mobile printer through android.

The process is as the invoice is generated the data is displayed in an html table on a new page where we have a print button. As the button is clicked, the data in the table should be printed.

Comment: If you browse to the site with any device and click print it should operate the same way - unless you're talking about making an app, in which case you will need to know Java.

Comment: thankx for ur reply. but its not the same as printing under android. in windows mobile we needed to pair the device and set a com port to print to but there's no pairing in android.